# Chrome images blink while IE and FF don't on DOM update in a specific case

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, dom

I'm building an interactive chat with AJAX and jQuery. Server side is working properly.

Here's a demo of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qNz9H/

**JQUERY:**

```
function writeTextToWindow() {
        var doc = $("#markChatMain0")[0];
        var str = "";

        str += "<div style='overflow:hidden;'>";
        str += '<img src="http://religiousdate.co.il/Image.ashx?id=';
        str += 137; //id
        str += '&amp;width=72&amp;height=71" style="max-height: 45px; position: relative;"/>';
        str += '<span style="border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); border-radius: 20px; width: 180px; word-wrap: break-word; padding: 5px; position: relative;">';
        str += "text"; //msg
        str += "</span></div>";

        doc.innerHTML += str;

        doc.scrollTop = doc.scrollHeight;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="markChatMain0" style="
    height:184px; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;background-color:yellow;">
    </div>
```

The image URL is generated on-the-go. I did put an actual reference to my site, because I couldn't replicate it on another image.

On Chrome, once the function is called and `doc.innerHTML += str` processed, for a second all images in the div are invisible and therefore the `doc.scrollHeight` value is a lot lower than the actual value. The expected behavior (such as witnessed on IE or FF) is that the images won't "blink" and that the real `scrollHeight` value will be passed.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images are all flickering for a second in chrome because instead of *appending* to your chat div, you're *redrawing* it all. In Firefox this might be handled a little nicer than Chrome, but rather than completely redraw an element you should try to append only what you need.

[Here is an updated version of your example](http://jsfiddle.net/qNz9H/4/). In it I have done the following:

- Appended new elements instead of redrawing the whole chat window
- Taken advantage of the jQuery library. Note there is a native JavaScript method `.appendChild` if you wanted to use it, but you were already using the jQuery library so it makes little sense not to use it to its fullest.
- Moved all of your styling into CSS, this makes more sense
- Generated a template for your images and spans. When we draw a row, we simply clone the templates

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#b").on("click", add_stuff);
});

var $img = $("<img src='http://religiousdate.co.il/Image.ashx?id=137&width=72&height=71' class='images' />"),
    $span = $("<span class='spans'>text</span>");

function add_stuff() {
    var $doc = $("#markChatMain0"),
        $row = $("<div class='row'></div>").append($img.clone(), $span.clone());
    $doc.append($row);
}
```

**CSS**:

```
#markChatMain0 {
    height:184px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    background:yellow;
}
.row {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.images {
    max-height:45px;
    height:71px;
    width:72px;
}
.spans {
    border:1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
    border-radius:20px;
    width:180px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    padding:5px;
}
```